# Uses for Honor Points other than gear

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have been looking around for things I can do with my Honor Points.

I have already bought all the Honor Gear (Season 15), but my extra Honor Points are now starting to build up again.

Things I have found and done:

1. Buy the **War Mounts** (2k Honor each) or Wintergrasp Mount (Black War Mammoth).
2. Buy **Legacy PvP Gear** as Transmogrification Sets.
3. Buy Cataclysm materials for whatever use (Such as **Embersilk Cloth** for bags).
4. Convert to **Justice Points**.
5. Buy **PvP Heirlooms** for Alt Characters.

I have looked around quite a bit and I am looking for more uses, if any are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wowhead has a list of all things obtainable with Honor Points:

There are [4343 items total](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=cr=158;crs=392;crv=0), from which [3178 items are still obtainable](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=cr=158:161;crs=392:1;crv=0:0):

- [950 Level 90 items that can be equipped](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=minrl=90;maxrl=90;cr=158:161:195;crs=392:1:1;crv=0:0:0)
- [2143 items under Level 90 that can be equipped](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=minrl=0;maxrl=89;cr=158:161:195;crs=392:1:1;crv=0:0:0) (mostly for Transmogrification but also including [31 Heirlooms](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=qu=7;minrl=1;maxrl=89;cr=158:161:195;crs=392:1:1;crv=0:0:0) and [10 Tabards](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=sl=19;cr=158:161;crs=392:1;crv=0:0))
- [85 other items](http://www.wowhead.com/items?filter=cr=158:161:195;crs=392:1:2;crv=0:0:0) (including Potions, Gem Designs, Gems, Mounts, Standards, Enchantments, Mists of Pandaria crafting materials)